# Multiline string interpolation on Google Workflows

Tags: yaml, google-workflows

I'm trying to use Google Workflows to do some automated BigQuery scheduling tasks. The requirement is to run a query on multiple datasets as the following:

```yaml
    - execute_query_job:
        call: execute_query_job
        args:
          query_text: >-
            SELECT 
            * EXCEPT(row_number)
            FROM (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uuid) row_number
            FROM
            `project.${database_id}.table`)
            WHERE
            row_number = 1
```

however, this doesn't work since the string is interpreted as is and no interpolation happened.
The `${}` syntax will not span over multiple lines and ansible syntax with `{{ var }}` also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the query to a single line in a similar fashion as:

```
- execute_query_job:
    call: execute_query_job
    args:
      query_text: ${"SELECT * EXCEPT(row_number) FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uuid) row_number FROM `project."+database_id+".table`) WHERE row_number = 1"}
```

Notice that as per [the Workflow's docs](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax#assign-step):

> Variables can be assigned to a particular value or to the result of an expression.

If that doesn't work notice that making a POST request to the [BigQuery's API jobs.insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) method will allow you to specify a [JobConfiguration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfiguration), where you could change the [defaultDataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationQuery.FIELDS.default_dataset) field and change this values for each different dataset at each iteration. The following [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/workflows-samples/blob/main/src/step_iterate.workflows.yaml) shows how to make iterations based on the values of an array in Workflows.

Comment: This does solve my current issue but doesn't really solve multiline string interpolation. Does this means that it cannot be done?

Comment: I couldn't find any evidence that this is supported on the public facing docs. I'll therefore believe it could be a nice Feature Request on their [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) even though there's still no component for Workflows.

Answer (score 1):

You may want take a look at the official [document](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/strings#concat-multiple-lines). you could concat the variable by multiple lines.

```
  - assign_vars:
  assign:
      - string: "say"
      - string: ${string+" "+"hello"}
      - string: ${string+" "+"to the world"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a necessary feature...

But in the meantime I have a more elegant solution:

```
- assign_vars:
    assign:
      - multilineVar: |
          #!/bin/bash
          echo Hi ${workflowVar}!
      - workflowVar: StackOverflow
      - multilineExapanded: ${ text.replace_all(multilineVar, ${workflowVar}, workflowVar) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish this were much easier, but this is what I've come up with when I need a multi line string to be posted somewhere:

```yaml
assign:
- my_multi_line_string: '${
    "*Something*: " + default(map.get(my_object, "key_in_object"), "Could not find key's value") +
    "\n*Foo*: " + my_var +
    "\n*Bar*: " + json.encode_to_string(a_list_of_strings)
    }'
```

Note the single quotes are required in this case to prevent funny business from the colons in the string.

Unfortunately, this is limited by Workflow's 400 character expression limit.